# How to get access token in apiview

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to get access token in my `APIView`. I am using `Oauth2` with `client_credentials`. Even it is printing `self.request.auth` and `self.request.user` as `None`. I want the user who have create `client_credentials` application in djnago restframework.

```
# Employee API
class EmployeeListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    # permission_classes = [UserIsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('request.user', self.request.auth)
        print('request.user', self.request.user)
        print('Access Token', self.access_token)

        qs = User.objects.exclude(
                Q(userprofile__user_is_deleted = True)|
                Q(userprofile__user_company__company_is_deleted=True)
            ).filter(
                Q(userprofile__user_company =self.request.auth.application.company) &
                Q(userprofile__user_role__id=4)
            )
        return qs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want access token you can get by `request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')`.

If you want user or client then you can

```
from django-oauth2-provider.provider.oauth2.models import AccessToken

accesstoken=AccessToken.objects.get(token=request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'))
user=accesstoken.user
client=accesstoken.client
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't leave comments yet, so I need to leave an answer :)
Are you sure your middleware settings are correct?

Here is an example, maybe it will help.
[How can I get the current logged in user from a django-oauth-toolkit token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906719/how-can-i-get-the-current-logged-in-user-from-a-django-oauth-toolkit-token)

It's actually pretty strange, that you cant get user with self.request.user. It's supposed to return him.

Try to print request object that you're getting in view and see what's inside, maybe it will help.